# Sass "extend" is not reflected in the @layer scope of Tailwind css

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css

**Problem**

Build "scss" into "css".
After execution, it will look like this.

If extend is not used, it works fine.
Is the way extend is written deprecated?
Or is there another way?

**Development environment**

OS: Linux Ubuntu22.04 LTS

use Webpack

- Sass : 1.62.1
- tailwindcss: 3.3.2
- postcss: 8.4.24

**source**

sample.scss

```scss
@use 'tailwind.css' as *;

%button {
  background: red;
}

@layer components {
  .sample {
    @apply text-white;
    @extend %button;
  }

  .sample2 {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

dist.css

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
.sample {
  background: red;
}

@layer components {
  .sample {
    @apply text-white;
  }
  .sample2 {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

postcss.config.cjs

```js
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.cjs')
  ]
};
```

tailwind.config.cjs

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/**/*.{html,ts,tsx,js,jsx}","./src/backend/static/*.{html,js,css}"],
  plugins: [],
  darkMode: 'class'
}
```

Want ".sample" to be within the scope of "components".

dist.css

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .sample {
    @apply text-white;
    background: red;
  }
  .sample2 {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was able to resolve it myself.**

sample.scss

```scss
@use 'tailwind.css' as *;

@layer components {
  %button {
    background: red;
  }
  .sample {
    @apply text-white;
    @extend %button;
  }

  .sample2 {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

dist.css

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@layer components {
  .sample {
    background: red;
  }
  .sample {
    @apply text-white;
  }
  .sample2 {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```